# jquery remove items from list after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can you help me with an ideea how i could remove items from a list after i click an item? let's say i have a list with 5 items and i press on the 3rd item, i want item4 and item5 to be removed. I want to remove all items after the one clicked in the list.Here is an html

```
<div class="row bcrumb">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="item"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Like you specifically only want to be able to click on 3 and remove 4 and 5 or you want to click on something and remove all items after the one clicked in the list?

Comment: yes i want to remove all items after the one clicked in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all list items after the clicked item:

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).nextAll().remove();
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEoXeg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth:child` selector to remove any item from a list like this:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(4)').remove();
$('ul li:nth-child(5)').remove();
```

However the question is a bit vague as to whether you want only those items to be removed on clicking 3rd item all the time or it should be a generic rule for other `li` items as well.

Because of this I cannot suggest which click event you should hook into. However I show you how to hook into 3rd `li` click:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3)').click(function) {
      console.log("3rd item clicked");
});
```